# Pre-select dropdown in a popup

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an application that manages events. For every event several rooms can be booked. Hence I created tables for `EVENTS`, for `ROOMS` and for `ROOM_BOOKINGS`.

`EVENTS` has a one-to-many relation with `ROOM_BOOKINGS` which itself has a many-to-one relation with `ROOMS`.

Now I would like to trigger a pop-up from the event details page to create a new room booking for the event. Using the form generator I get a dropdown for the event the room binding should be tied to.

I would like to set this dropdown in form for a new room booking to the event that is shown on the current event details page and disable editing by the user.

I tried to set the options of the dropdown using the button that triggers the popup:

```
app.popups.AddRoomBooking.visible = true;
var currentEvent = [widget.datasource.item];
app.popups.AddRoomBooking.descendants.roomsbookedField.options = currentEvent;
```

But this not only feels weird, it also doesn't work, returning:

> Fri Jul 06 12:18:10 GMT+200 2018 Expected List to match
>   List. at
>   EventDetailPage.roomBookingPanel.room_bookings_table.addRoomBooking.onClick:4:64

**I guess the fundamental problem is that I do not understand what needs to be passed to a dropdown if it should represent a many-to-one relation.**

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do is to bind the dropdown value to your datasource field you want it to update, and then your script should set the value on the datasource, and from there the dropdown will show the datasource value.

So for example if dropdown had options A, B or C, and the dropdown VALUE was bound to a create datasource relation field X, then the script would be:
CreateDatasource.item.fieldX = widget.datasource.item 
(or if the relation field is many, then CreateDatasource.item.fieldX.push(widget.datasource.item).